# Oscillating function with frequency->infinity at x=0

Tags: real-analysis

A fellow student has mentioned the idea of a function that oscillates very fast near 0.

I guess it looks like this: [image: function]
Can someone give me an example what function this could be?
sin(1/x) would come to my mind, but not sure.
What would be other functions that don't in any way include sin/cos/tan (ect)

Oh, since someone in the comments meant that oscillating functions without trig don't exist, i make it broader: give me a function that doesn't have to look "curvy" that makes very fast zigzags at 0. (with a finite "definition table" or how its called)

Comment: Hem, what does "etc" include ?

Comment: @ZacharySelk: why ?

Comment: @ZacharySelk i edited my question a little^^

Comment: Why do you want this? Why disallow trig functions?

Comment: @MikeHaskel well, because with trigs its kinda easy, i mean the point of trigs is that they oscilate, i just wanted some nontrig examples to visualize it myself

Comment: Why in the world is this being downvoted?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 some people are just mean i guess ^_^ thanks for the upper =) The dumb thing is, i don't even know what they don't like, so i can't possibly improve my further questions.

Comment: @saturatedexpo No problem. There's a general set of things that we look for when users post questions. The question should be clear, it should be about math, and you should have put some effort and thought into it. This meets all of these criterion.

Comment: You might better use a graphing software....

Comment: and then? get a graph of a function i dont know... troll ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard example is the "topologists' sine curve' which is your $\sin(1/x)$.

But here is one that is even whackier, using just the "floor" function ($\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer not greater than $x$) and absolute value:

$$
f(x) = \left\lfloor 2^{\left\lfloor |\frac{1}{x}| \right\rfloor} \right\rfloor x
-2  \left\lfloor 2^{\left\lfloor |\frac{1}{x}| \right\rfloor -1} \right\rfloor x
$$
This is the $\lfloor |1/x| \rfloor$-th bit of the binary expansion of $x$.  It goes absolutely whackadoo near $x=0$ yet I believe it is piecewise constant and continuous almost everywhere and it is a (Lebesgue) integrable function.

The oscilations are so fast that if Mathematica plots it from $-.1$ to $.1$ the area near zero is plotted as all zeros (because of roundoff headaches involving subtracting two very large numbers), and Mathematica usually doesn't have such issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like trigonometric functions, what about the [Bessel functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+besselJ0(1%2Fx)) then ?